# Try and Except Python

Tags: python, function, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I did this example but it does not run with the try and except handling errors in Python.

```
def my_fun(numCats):
    print('How many cats do you have?')
    numCats = input()
    try:
        if int(numCats) >=4:
            print('That is a lot of cats')
        else:
            print('That is not that many cats')
    except ValueError:
        print("Value error")
```

I tried:

```
except Exception:
except  (ZeroDivisionError,ValueError) as e:
except  (ZeroDivisionError,ValueError) as error:
```

I did other example and it was able to catch `ZeroDivisionError`
I am using Jupyter notebook Python 3. 
**Any help in this matter is highly appreciated.**

I am calling

```
my_fun(int('six'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-657852cb9525> in <module>()
----> 1 my_fun(int('six'))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'six'
```

Comment: Your example runs just fine if you fix the indentation and call the function.

Comment: "it does not run"- what do you mean? what output do you get? did you call the function?

Comment: do you have to add some library or something? Also, I was using my_fun(int('six')) to test it. Yeah, it should run because it is an example but I maybe missing something.

Comment: It is 3. I run it

Comment: Well you're problem is `my_fun(int('six'))` should be `my_fun('six')`, don't call `int()` there where it isn't caught, also delete the line with `input()`, it is not required is you parse an argument to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems:

1. Please fix the indentation. The indentation levels are mismatched.
2. There's no need to take in the parameter `numCats` as it's changed to whatever the user provides anyway.
3. You're not calling the function `my_fun()`, meaning that there will never be any output, as functions only run when called.

This should work:

```
def my_fun():
    print('How many cats do you have?\n')
    numCats = input()
    try:
        if int(numCats) > 3:
            print('That is a lot of cats.')
        else:
            print('That is not that many cats.')
    except ValueError:
        print("Value error")  

my_fun() ## As the function is called, it will produce output now
```

Comment: Very helpful! I think you are def right about it all! Thanks

Comment: @Mayra No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reworked version of your code:

```
def my_fun():
    numCats = input('How many cats do you have?\n')
    try:
        if int(numCats) >= 4:
            return 'That is a lot of cats'
        else:
            return 'That is not that many cats'
    except ValueError:
        return 'Error: you entered a non-numeric value: {0}'.format(numCats)

my_fun()
```

**Explanation**

- You need to call your function for it to run, as above.
- Indentation is important. This has been made consistent with guidelines.
- `input()` takes as a parameter a string which is displayed before the input.
- Since the user provides input via `input()`, your function does not require an argument.
- It is good practice to `return` values and, if necessary, print them afterwards. Rather than having your function `print` strings and `return` None.
- Your error can be more descriptive, and include the inappropriate input itself.

Comment: Their indentation was ok no?

Comment: @Chris_Rands, OP was updated. It originally had 8 spaces. Which may work fine. But not conventional.